# Free website to obtain corporate bond's data similar to cbonds?

Tags: data, market

Does anyone know of any website where I can obtain corporate bond's data in the same fashion as "cbonds" (they let you look up by issuer, maturity, etc.). Ideally free?

I need to know bond issues by Rio de Janeiro in Brazil.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - for other countries - of course not.

But in case of Brazil, you are lucky. Brazil is more advanced than most other countries in this regard. All the debentures are exchange-listed and easy to find. You can see all the debentures, for example, on https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures or http://www.debentures.com.br/exploreosnd/consultaadados/emissoesdedebentures/caracteristicas_r.asp?tip_deb=publicas&op_exc=todos

Notes:

The "download" link at the bottom of the debentures page will give you all the debentures and all the data fields in .csv format.

Some of these debentures have no secondary market. Someone buys everything at the time of origination and holds to maturity.